# Run FIrebase Cloud Function for more than 9 mins (540 sec)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

so I have a piece of asynchronous(setInterval) code in the firebase function.

```js
export const auto_play = functions
  .runWith({ memory: "512MB", timeoutSeconds: 540 })
  .pubsub.schedule("*/15 * * * *")
  .onRun(async (context) => {

      const nums = polledDoc.data()?.nums as number[];
      setInterval(() => {
        const polledNum = nums.shift();
        // function suppose to run for atleast 10-15 mins coz nums.length can be any number from 60 to 90.
        // a function which save data to realtime database
        autoPollAlgo({ gameId: scheduledGame.docs[0].id, number: polledNum as number });
      }, 10 * 1000);
})
```

now this code works fine 3/5 times but it sometimes exits from intervals before the num array completes. sometimes it just got stop after a min and sometimes after 5mins.

I know the fact functions have a max timeout of 9mins, but how does this async code work even after 9mins.

after some digging found out I'm not returning any promise so this code can terminate any time. now to make things perfect I added a promise code to the end of the block.

```js
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true);
     //to  make sure it exit after 15mins when interval code is done.
      }, 900000);
    });
```

now what is happening, functions is got consistent now its end exactly after 9mins(in the middle of setinterval exec.). it won't wait for the promise to resolve.

how can I keep a function to run an async task for 15mins with consistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with cloud functions I came with a solution.
I divided the logic into two functions.
First, I divided the `nums` array in half.

I executed setInterval for half of the nums then I use Cloud Pub/Sub to execute another function with the other half nums.

```js
// somewhere in first function
pubSubClient.topic("play_half").publish(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(restNum), "utf-8"), { gameId: scheduledGame.docs[0].id });

export const auto_play_2 = functions
  .runWith({ memory: "512MB", timeoutSeconds: 540 })
  .pubsub.topic("play_half")
  .onPublish((message) => {

    const non_parse_arr = Buffer.from(message.data, "base64").toString();
   //other half nums
    const nums = JSON.parse(non_parse_arr);
   //...

})
```